# Range of Multiple Unavailabe Dates not showing properly in react daterange picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Multiple Unavailable dates are not shown properly using react-daterange-picker.

[Documentation](https://github.com/onefinestay/react-daterange-picker) says to pass an array of objects with start and end moments of unavailable blocks. But it is not showing the result as expected. It is showing unavailable dates correctly but in a zigzag fashion.

**Component**

```
    class DatePicker extends React.Component {
    .....     
    render() {
        return (    
                {this.state.isOpen && (
                    <DateRangePicker
                        firstOfWeek={1}
                        numberOfCalendars={2}
                        selectionType='range'
                        minimumDate={moment()}
                        stateDefinitions={stateDefinitions}
                        dateStates={this.state.BadDates}
                        defaultState="available"
                        showLegend={true}
                        value={this.state.value}
                        onSelect={this.onSelect}
                        singleDateRange={false}
                        selectionType="range"
                        maximumDate={moment().startOf('month').add(4, 'months')}
                    />
                )}
        );
    }
}
export default DatePicker;
```

**Helpers**

```
export function returnUnavailableDays(allDates) {
    const unavailableDates = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < allDates.length; i++) {
        const moment1 = moment(allDates[i].check_in);
        const moment2 = moment(allDates[i].check_out);
        if (moment1 >= moment()) {
        unavailableDates.push(
            {
            state: 'unavailable',
            range: moment.range(
                moment1,
                moment2,
            ),
            },
        );
        }
    }
    return unavailableDates;
}
```

I am not sure what can go wrong in passing the value of the array to the DateRangePicker as a prop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the term *Zig-zag* in the question refers to the pattern shown in the Image below.[image]

You're doing all correct but you are forgetting to add a this line of code at the end of the helper function `returnUnavailableDays()`.

**After adding this line to your code**

```
unavailableDates.sort((a, b) => (moment(a.range.start).isBefore(moment(b.range.start)) ? -1 : 1));
```

**Your helper should look like**

```
export function returnUnavailableDays(allBookings) {
const unavailableDates = [];
for (let i = 0; i < allBookings.length; i++) {
    const moment1 = moment(allBookings[i].check_in);
    const moment2 = moment(allBookings[i].check_out);
    if (moment1 >= moment()) {
    unavailableDates.push(
        {
        state: 'unavailable',
        range: moment.range(
            moment1,
            moment2,
        ),
        },
    );
    }
}
unavailableDates.sort((a, b) => (moment(a.range.start).isBefore(moment(b.range.start)) ? -1 : 1));
return unavailableDates;
}
```

Basically What it does is that it provides your date ranges in chronological order. Refer [this issue](https://github.com/onefinestay/react-daterange-picker/issues/192) for more info.

Finally output should look like this Image.
[image]

Comment: Yes, you're correct. The problem lies into the sorting of the array. The input should be in chronological order.